# Why does the browser hangs when I'm running a ghostscript process in a laravel application?

Tags: laravel, process

I'm building a PDF compressor app with Laravel 10. I'm using the Process class to execute the Ghostscript command on the server:

```
$cmd = "gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile={$output} {$input}";
$process = new Process(explode(' ', $cmd));
$process->setTimeout(3600);
$process->run();
```

The above code works as expected and the compressed PDF is generated successfully.

The only issue I have is that during the compression process, the page cannot be reloaded and hangs until the process finishes.

Is there a way I can kill the process when I reload the page or is there a better way to handle this type applications?

Comment: You can do it using [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#creating-jobs), I think it's better to use `Laravel Jobs` for your need.

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript is NOT a compressor , far from it, it is a print file rewriter. Which means files can often be bigger not smaller as components get added.

Take this example that covers many different types of common PDF features in just one page.

[image]

Things to note are the file is bigger and objects are missing.

source has 60 objects and conversion has 68 So why a difference?

Well

- The version has been downgraded from 1.7 (most common) into lessor 1.4 thus any 1.5 1.6 or 1.7 features are regenerated if possible in 1.4 compatible objects (may require some converted into 2 or more objects, but that may not always be possible.
- There were some fonts needed altering which often adds more or less objects. If running silent (-q or -dQUITE) you will not see if there is any hang due to fonts.

```
Loading font Helvetica (or substitute) from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular
Loading CIDFont KaiTi_GB2312 substitute from %rom%Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf
Loading CIDFont STSong-Light substitute from %rom%Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf
```

- And GS will not transfer objects that are not specifically targeted when present so the QRcode and transparent over stamp were not especially handled. (Though there seems to be some odd red residue on the right?)

So overall the file has been reduced to a bigger more standards compatible file. The majority of PDF are already optimally compressed so attempting to recompress generically is a route to disaster, custom targeting of each object one by one, is required to determine if existing object compression is good enough for fast decompression or if a gain may be made (rare except in B&W imaged files).

Note a very similar source file was halved in number of bytes (even when  **including  the added fonts**) in a different GhostScript run without messing about with 1.7 features or /ebook resolution so simply just "rebuild". Where it determined compression could be "bettered" for some objects and deleted none !

Specific to your question is that GS (as with all PDF manipulation) must have exclusive processor use of 100% of both input and output files until all threads complete and the process is naturally finished. So in effect a serial task using parallel processes internally that usually cannot be externally threaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro. I didn't know that. I appreciate it